# Automating a checkout process for a charity using Python

Tags: python, bots, e-commerce

I apologise in advance for the vagueness of this question - I am quite new to all this.

I am making a website that allows you to donate to various charities through the website (i.e. rather than redirecting you to that charities website, it allows you to donate straight from my website).

I am currently focusing on getting this working for the international rescue committee. Their donate page is here : https://help.rescue-uk.org/

I struggling to figure out what they are actually using to process payments. They have MaxMind but this seems to be an antifraud measure.

If anyone could give me some advice for where to start in terms of automating this process, I would be really grateful!

Again apologies, I am a newb

I realise I'll probably need to use selenium and headless browsing which I've done a bit of before. Any other help with getting started still very much appreciated (or if you don't think this is right)

Alternatively, is there an API that does this? Was looking at JustGiving but seemed to want to redirect